# Запрос Select с объединением и группировкой

Tags: sql-server

Всем доброго времени суток.
Имеются две таблицы - Таблица "Order" (это таблица заказов книг с полями "Name" - имя заказчика и "ID_book" - номер заказанной книги) и Таблица "Books" (это таблица книг с полями "ID_book" - номер книги и "Title" - это название книги). Конечно в таблицах есть и другие столбцы, но они нас не интересуют.
Необходимо написать запрос на языке SQL, который выводит на экран следующую сводную информацию в табличном виде по всем заказчикам:
Name (имя заказчика) и Count_books (количество заказанных им книг, содержащих в названии слово "учебник").
Мои наработки не приносят нужного результата, в чем допущена ошибка?:

```
 Books.Title,
     (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM Orders WHERE Orders.ID_book = Books.ID_Book) AS ToolsCount
FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Books ON Books.ID_book=Orders.ID_Book WhERE  Books.Title LIKE '%Учебник%'
```

Comment: Начните с того, что у вас в селекте даже нет имени заказчика. Как вы тогда хотите получить его имя в результате?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
select Orders.Name, count(1) Count_books from Orders
join Books on Books.ID_book = Orders.ID_book and Books.Title like '%Учебник%'
group by Orders.Name
```

Если нужно, чтобы в списке имён были и те, у кого таких книг нет, но они совершали другие заказы (у них Count_books = 0), то:

```
select distinct Orders.Name, coalesce(Count_books, 0) as Count_books from Orders
left join (
  select Orders.Name, count(1) Count_books from Orders
join Books on Books.ID_book = Orders.ID_book and Books.Title like '%Учебник%'
group by Orders.Name) c on c.Name = Orders.Name
```

По поводу ваших ошибок:

1. Вы плохо скопировали пример на SO. Ваш запрос нерабочий. Как минимум пропущен SELECT
2. Вам нужно два поля Name и Count_books, судя по тексту. Их обоих нет в селекте. Видимо вы не вникли в задание.
3. В суть вашего запроса нет сил вникать. Я не настолько хорош в SQL и заинтересован, чтобы пытаться это понять. Я абсолютно не понял вашего хода мыслей. Рекомендую по отдельности вникнуть как работают группировки и разные виды джоинов.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо, разобрался благодаря Вам )